# How do I iterate though a list of files that contain more than one dynamic variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am grabbing log type info from AWS S3 for processing.
I have setup a script that grabs each set of logs for the week and brings it over to my script in the format of file1, file2 etc - these are discarded so names aren't important.
I then run comparisons on previous weeks for changes.
Im having issues calling the file names in a loop as so:

```
filename1="information set bla bla (info1)"
filename2="information set bla bla (info2)"
for i in 1 2; do
  echo $filename$i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a use case for an array.

```
filenames=(
  "information set bla blank (info1)" 
  "information set bla blank (info1)"
)

for f in "${filenames[@]}"; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

If you really need the integer `i` for some reason, you can iterate over the array indices:

```
for i in "${!filenames[@]}"; do
  echo "$i: ${filenames[i]}"
done
```